# R sum in a while loop

Tags: php

I have loop and display this row

```
<? 
  if ($objResult["cashier_trans_Type"]=="out" || 
      $objResult["cashier_trans_Type"]=="debit to customer" ||
      $objResult["cashier_trans_Type"]=="debit") { 
      echo "0.00"; 
  } else {
      echo $Dofaa=number_format($objResult["cashier_trans_Value"],2); 
  } 
?>
```

Now I would like to use a while loop in order to do the sum for the all columns: `$Dofaa`

How can I do this by php?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a new loop. Just add to the total with each of you `else` loops.

```
<?
$Dofaa_total = 0; // create a total variable
...
  if ($objResult["cashier_trans_Type"]=="out" || 
  $objResult["cashier_trans_Type"]=="debit to customer" ||
  $objResult["cashier_trans_Type"]=="debit") { 
  echo "0.00"; 
} else {
  echo $Dofaa=number_format($objResult["cashier_trans_Value"],2);
     $Dofaa_total += $Dofaa;  // add to the total variable
 } 
...
echo $Dofaa_total;  // echo the total variable
?>
```